# how to implement image slide using collection view Ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i have been told to implement slider using a collection view
but i am pretty clueless how to implement a slider like this(shown below) through collection view

http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-slider.slider for eg a slider like this

i thought of using 1 dynamic collectionview populating an image on imageview on click event but what i wanted was a sliding of images rather than on CollectionView cell click..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad, but I'll do my best to help get you started:

First you'll wanna to set up a collection view with `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. The cells in this collection view image scrolling cell should contain its own collection view of custom cells containing the image and conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as well.

This will essentially get you started with a base collection view. See [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started) for more details on getting started with collection views.

For the automatic paging effect you want to emulate, I've included some relevant posts below:

- [Create a Paging UICollectionView with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355226/create-a-paging-uicollectionview-with-swift)
- [UICollectionView Auto Scroll Paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842897/uicollectionview-auto-scroll-paging)

A late response, but I hope this may be of use!

Comment: hey I have implemented this using the same. Its been a while though. Thanks anyways